# Django recursive relationship

Tags: django, recursion

I'm using Django 1.5 and am struggling with something that I guess is pretty basic.

I've got following Persons model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    contact_person = models.ManyToManyField(ContactPerson)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
...
```

The goal is to add a **partner** of the person to the model. I don't want the partner or the person to be superior to the other; they should be equal. 
In other words, when looking up a person, his/her partner should appear as well (if there is one). I need to be able to add the partner once, either at the woman's or at the men's side (I don't want to link them two times).

I've searched the documentation for OneToOneFields, but recursive OneToOnes don't seem to be supported, i.e. I get a NameError ("name 'Person' is not defined") when I try:

```
partner = models.OneToOneField(Person, blank=true, null=true)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can a `Person` be `parent` of several other `Persons`? or only 1 'son' is allowed.

Comment: Actually I don't need/want the parent-sun relationship. I want a partner to be equal to person (a partner is a person anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    partner = models.OneToOneField('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, checkPartner = True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Person, self).save()
        if self.partner and checkPartner:
            self.partner.partner = self
            self.partner.save(checkPartner = False)
```

- Null true on partner field, has to be enabled because the first person to be saved will not have any partner.
- checkPartner parameter has been added so that save() doesn't fall into an infinite loop

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

```
partner = models.OneToOneField('Person', blank=true, null=true)
```

or in alternative, if you're on the same class

```
partner = models.OneToOneField('self', blank=true, null=true)
```

quotes are everything, in this case

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # call to super, we want self.partner to be set
    super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # this is necessary to avoid infinite save loops on partner's save call
    # at this point, you have a partner
    # this won't work if your partner has already a partner
    # but it's easy to go from here
    if not self.partner.partner:
        self.partner.partner = self
        self.partner.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, when a partner (person 2) is picked for person 1, the person 2 isn't automatically linked to person 1. That's what I was afraid for.

Comment: You want the foreignkey updated in person2 after you update it in person1?

Comment: I think that's the way indeed. Once I select a partner for any of the two persons (let's say person2 is selected as a partner for person1), then I don't want to go to partner2 and select partner1 as his/her parner there.

Comment: You could write your own custom save method. I'll try to sketch something out for you

Comment: With the custom save method above, I get "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partner'" on the first person save.