# Multiple ForeignKeys in Through model for Many-to-many relation to same model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I've got a many-to-many relation from a model called Resource to itself through an intermediary model called RelatedResource:

```
class Resource(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True) # book title, person's name, video title, etc.
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True) # dynamically generated for youtube and amazon; todo: uniqueness
    resourceID = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) # todo: uniqueness
    picture = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    ...

class RelatedResource(models.Model):
    input = models.ForeignKey(Resource, related_name="input_resource")
    output = models.ForeignKey(Resource, related_name="output_resource")
    input_affiliate = models.ForeignKey(Resource, related_name="while_with", blank=True, null=True)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...
```

Django complains that having more than 2 foreign keys to Resource is ambiguous, of course, because then it doesn't know which two of the three ForeignKey fields apply in the many-to-many relation.

Is there any way I can keep all 3 ForeignKey fields in the intermediary model and tell Django which 2 are meant for the many-to-many relation?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is recursive relationship.
It is described in here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships

And here.
[Django recursive relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271001/django-recursive-relationship)

Comment: It seems like a recursive relationship is many-to-one. I need M2M.

I ended up getting rid of the M2M relationship and keeping the 3 ForeignKey relationships. That's working fine so far.